# How to interconnect C# Socket with ESP8266 (Hardware TCP)

Tags: c#, tcp, esp8266, nodemcu

I am trying to create a GUI to an ESP8266 project that I have already developed. The boards are using the NodeMCU firmware, and I am loading programs on through the ESP8266 Arduino Core. I am using C# for my GUI program on Windows.

Here is my debug code for the ESP8266 (in Arduino):

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
String ConnectedMAC[8];
IPAddress ConnectedIP[8];
WiFiClient clientforcom;
void setup() {
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_AP_STA);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  int f = WiFi.scanNetworks();
  Serial.println("Scanning Networks");
  delay(5000);
  for (int n = 0; n < f; n++) {
    Serial.println(WiFi.SSID(n));
  }
  WiFi.begin(ssid, passtring); //SSID and passtring are my home network credentials
  delay(2000);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(100);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.print("The IP of this node is: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
}


void loop() {

  MACManagement();
  WiFiServer serverforclient(WiFi.localIP(), 25565);
  while (!serverforclient.hasClient()) { //this does not work with Socket or delay is too long
    delay(50);
    Serial.println("Waiting for client");
  }
  clientforcom = serverforclient.available();
  while (clientforcom.available() <= 0) {
    delay(50);
    Serial.println("Waiting for response");
  }
  String response = clientforcom.readString();
  if (response.startsWith("GetController")) {
    Serial.println("Sending String");
    clientforcom.println("Returned String");
  }
}


void MACManagement() {

  unsigned char number_client;
  struct station_info *stat_info;

  struct ip_addr *IPaddress;
  IPAddress address;
  int i = 0;

  number_client = wifi_softap_get_station_num();
  stat_info = wifi_softap_get_station_info();

  Serial.print(" Total Connected Clients are = ");
  Serial.println(number_client);

  while (stat_info != NULL) {

    IPaddress = &stat_info->ip;
    address = IPaddress->addr;

    Serial.print("client= ");

    Serial.print(i);
    Serial.print(" IP adress is = ");
    Serial.print((address));
    ConnectedIP[i] = address;
    Serial.print(" with MAC adress is = ");

    Serial.print(stat_info->bssid[0], HEX); Serial.print(" ");
    Serial.print(stat_info->bssid[1], HEX); Serial.print(" ");
    Serial.print(stat_info->bssid[2], HEX); Serial.print(" ");
    Serial.print(stat_info->bssid[3], HEX); Serial.print(" ");
    Serial.print(stat_info->bssid[4], HEX); Serial.print(" ");
    Serial.print(stat_info->bssid[5], HEX); Serial.print(" ");
    ConnectedMAC[i] = String(stat_info->bssid[0], HEX) + ":" + String(stat_info->bssid[1], HEX) + ":" + String(stat_info->bssid[2], HEX) + ":" + String(stat_info->bssid[3], HEX) + ":" + String(stat_info->bssid[4], HEX) + ":" + String(stat_info->bssid[5], HEX);
    stat_info = STAILQ_NEXT(stat_info, next);
    i++;
    Serial.println();
  }
}
```

and here is my network accessing code in C#:

```
void loadUI(){
            enterIPLabel.Visible=false;
            errorBox.Text="Connecting to Leader node";
            tcpcom=new TcpClient(leadernode.ToString(),25565);
            tcpcom.Connect(leadernode.ToString(),25565);
            while(!tcpcom.Connected);

            tcpcom.Client.Send(System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("GetController"));
            errorBox.Text="Awaiting Node Response";
            while(tcpcom.Available<=0); //hopefully this should stop this method from executing until the response is made
            //FILL IN CODE FOR RETURN STATEMENT
            tabController.Visible=true;
            NodeMap.Visible=true;
        }
```

However, when I reach the "Waiting for Client" section of the ESP8266 code and I run the C# program, entering the IP Address into leadernode. I get an error from .NET that states:

```
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

I have no idea why the ESP8266 would be refusing the connection, I put delays such that the Software Watch Dog would not initiate, so I don't understand why it would break the program.

Comment: Looks like your port number is in the wrong byte order.  Sockets (e.g. C#) functions need network byte order.  No idea about the ESP helper functions.  Port number mismatch will result in the "Connection refused." error

Comment: How would I solve that issue?